Is it correct usage of @Bean and @Value annotations?
Overall, this class sets up configurations for formatting date and time types, adding authentication headers, and defining the logging level for the Feign client used in the organization structure client. The internalKey property is a key component for authentication.
What do you think about this class with @Bean and @Value inside, but without any stereotype annotation, such a @Component or @Configuration?
public class OrgClientConfig {
    protected final org.slf4j.Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    @Value("${aut.internalKey}")
    private String internalKey;

    @Bean
    public FeignFormatterRegistrar localDateFeignFormatterRegistrar() {
        return formatterRegistry -> {

            // just handling JSR-310 specific date and time types
            DateTimeFormatterRegistrar registrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();
            registrar.setUseIsoFormat(true);
            registrar.registerFormatters(formatterRegistry);

            // handles Joda-specific types as well as Date, Calendar, Long
            JodaTimeFormatterRegistrar jodaRegister = new JodaTimeFormatterRegistrar();
            jodaRegister.setUseIsoFormat(true);
            jodaRegister.registerFormatters(formatterRegistry);

            // regular DateFormat-based Date, Calendar, Long converters
            new DateFormatterRegistrar().registerFormatters(formatterRegistry);


            // custom formatters
            formatterRegistry.addFormatter(new DateFormatter());
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
        return new InternalKeyRequestInterceptor(internalKey);
    }

    @Bean
    Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.FULL;
    }

}

I think this class is useless in fact. It settles in separate library.
The library does not have any resource folder.
Now I am rewriting the code to Java 17 from Java 8, from Spring boot 1xx to Spring boot 3xxx. And in new version of the class I started to get error that internalKey is null, which was not problem for Java8.
Why do they use @Value, if there is no any properties file there?
Why do they use @Bean without @Component or @Configuration above the class? Do you find this as incorrect code?

Is it wrong, I have no idea if it is without seeing it in context that is impossible to know. @Bean methods in a class can make sense if this class itself is being used in an @Import or itself as an @Bean then you don't need @Component. It could be automatically loaded as an auto-configuration which wouldn't need it as well.  It could also serve as a base class to other classes again no need for @Component. The fact that it complains about the internalKey being null indicates that it is at least used somewhere but apparently you broke the @Value resolution.


What do you think about this class with @Bean and @Value inside, but without any stereotype annotation, such a @Component or @Configuration?

I would not be loaded by Spring and the bean declarations would take no effect, so it becomes a dead piece code. The only viable ways that come to my mind on how to work with this class correctly are:

Annotate it with @Component or better @Configuration and either make it appear in the @ComponentScan or better @Import it.
Annotate it with @AutoConfiguration and include in META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports  (or import through @ImportAutoConfiguration, though I have never use it before).
Declare it a different configuration class as a @Bean, though it does not make much sense to me.

A justifiable case would be making the whole thing abstract as an abstraction for various configuration classes, though you have to follow the rules to avoid potential conflicts.
In any case, unless it is loaded by Spring, it is a dead and misleading code.
